# Temperature estimation via Kalman filter

Tags: estimation, kalman-filters

Based on the recommendation I would like to ask you for your opinion regarding my [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/705213/kalman-filter-for-estimation-of-braking-resistor-temperature?noredirect=1#comment1876310_705213) I have asked on different forum.